# Get list of tasks numbers from git log based on message

Tags: git, git-log

Task number = JIRA issue number = **** (E.g.: 7600)

Let's suppose that I have a list of commits having the following messages:

```
PRJ-7600 - first message
PRJ-8283 - second message
PRJ-8283 - third message
PRJ-1001 - fourth message
PRJ-8283 - fifth message
PRJ-7600 - sixth message
```

where the first one is for the oldest commit.

**Wanted** output:

```
1001
7600
8283
```

I listed my commits using the following command:

```
git log --author="First Last" --oneline --grep=PRJ --pretty=format:"%s" | sort
```

where

- committer = author (in this case)
- `--grep=PRJ` is specified to ignore the comments that were automatically generated ("*Merge branch ...*") (alternative to `--no-merges`)
- `--pretty=format:"%s"` shows only the message (removes the hash)

**Actual** output:

```
PRJ-1001 - fourth message
PRJ-7600 - first message
PRJ-7600 - sixth message
PRJ-8283 - fifth message
PRJ-8283 - second message
PRJ-8283 - third message
```

Is it possible to extract those numbers (probably using regex or something like substring) showing them only once?

**Details:**

- Windows 7
- git 1.9.5 (msysgit) -> used from cmd, not from Git Bash console

Comment: Do you use `git-bash`? IIUC, on `Linux` you could use `sed`, `sort` and `uniq` to do that but I don't know whether these tools are available on `Windows`.

Comment: I edited my post according to your comment. I'll also try to use the other hints. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't all commits for a single task be on a branch?

Comment: What tools can be used? It can be solved in both Git Bash (easier, as @ArkadiuszDrabczyk mentioned) and in a batch-file but the code will be completely different.

Comment: Any solution that provides the expected output is welcome. It is good for the other members that encounter the same problem to have many possible solutions. I'll also post a solution when I'll have one.

Comment: there's a good DAS screencast on this and similar stats using git. https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/statistics-over-git-repositories

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do it in either bash or git bash:

```
git log --author="First Last" --oneline --grep=PRJ --pretty=format:"%s" | sort | cut --delimiter='-' --fields=2 | uniq
```

So building on the first section posted in the question, the extra is:

```
| cut --delimiter='-' --fields=2 | uniq
```

this pipes the sorted output to `cut` which extracts the 2nd field delimited by a hyphen "-" and the result is then pipes to `uniq` to display the distinct values.

This solution has a weakness in the form of the delimiter used for `cut` - if the format of the log message changes, then it may break.
A better solution would be to use a regex search (instead of `cut`) for the issue key ("/PRJ-.+\s/" I think...) and output the number part.

### EDIT

So after a bit of digging, it is possible to do this a little more reliably using `grep` to find the item key (**PRJ** in this case):

```
git log ... | grep -oP --regexp="PRJ-\K\d+" | uniq
```

`-o` tells grep to output only the matched part of the line
`-P` is use the PCRE (perl/PHP) flavour of regex, thus enabling us to use the
`\K` option which causes the matches prior (to that point) to be excluded